# Why doesn't it work with Python and discord.py

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to do a simple thing like a command with discord.py, but it doesn't give anything like an error in the terminal or in Discord.

Here is the code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class BotLibertarin(discord.Client):
    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")

    @client.command()
    async def teste(ctx,*,arg):
        await ctx.channel.send(arg)

    @client.event
    async def on_message(self, message):
        print(f"message from {message.author} what he said {message.content}")


client = BotLibertarin()
client.run("")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how exactly your class is structured because of the improper indentation or why you're assigning `client` twice, but you need to subclass [`commands.Bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot) to use the commands extension, not [`Client`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client).

Also, you need to use [`Bot.process_commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands) in your `on_message` handler.

See the [Why does `on_message` make my commands stop working? section of the FAQ in discord.py's documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working).

Comment: ok let me see if i undestantd what exactly you're saying, i'll need one subclass like CommandHandler(commands.Bot) ?

Comment: You don't need to subclass if you're not overriding any methods. If you do subclass, you need to subclass `commands.Bot` to use the commands extension. Right now, you have two separate clients, the instance of `BotLibertarin`, your `Client` subclass, which is what you're running, and its attribute, which is an instance of `commands.Bot` and isn't being run. You've registered the command and event handler for the `commands.Bot` instance. The only reason the event handler also works for the `BotLibertarin` instance is because you're overriding it in the subclass as well.